# Tooltip displaying undefined values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I am having some issues with tooltips for my bar graph. For each stopname column, there should be a corresponding value of boarding and alightings shown in the tooltip, however, I am getting undefined values like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjILu.png)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 300, left: 40},
    width = 1250 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 750 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["orange", "orangered"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Stop:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.stopname + "</span>" + "<br><br><strong>Mean no. of boardings:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.meanboardings + "</span>"+ "<br><br><strong>Mean no. of alightings:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.meanalightings + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d){
  return {
    stopname: d.stopname,
    meanboardings: +d.meanboardings,
    meanalightings: +d.meanalightings
  };
}, function(error, data) {
  console.log(data);

  var dataset = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "stopname"
});

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.passengers = dataset.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.stopname; }));
  x1.domain(dataset).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.passengers, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", "-.5em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-90)" 
                });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Mean no. of boardings and alightings");

  var stopname = svg.selectAll(".stopname")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "stopname")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.stopname) + ",0)"; });

  stopname.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.passengers; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);


  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(dataset.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })

});

function type(d) {
  d.data = +d.data;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

TSV file:

```
stopname    maxboardings    meanboardings   minboardings    varboardings    maxalightings   meanalightings  minalightings   varalightings   maxload meanload    minload varload noofbuses
The Boardwalk Terminal (3908)   7   2.571428571 0   6.952380952 0   0   0   0   7   2.571428571 0   6.952380952 7
Highview / Sugar Maple (3329)   2   0.333333333 0   0.666666667 1   0.166666667 0   0.166666667 6   3   0   6.4 6
Highview / Highview Pl (3330)   0   0   0   0   1   0.166666667 0   0.166666667 5   2.833333333 0   5.366666667 6
....
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined because you are using an undefined value for generating tooltip text.

In your `html` function, the data-object associated `d` you get for every rectangle/bar is of following format:

```
{name: "meanlightings", value: <some_value>}
```

It does not contain the `stopname` property and will only contain value for one of the fields in the original dataset.

You will have to rewrite the `html` callback as

```
.html(function(d) {
  return "<strong>" + d.name + " :</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.value + "</span>";
})
```

However, if you want to show more properties, you will have to change the data that you are binding to rectangles.